# High frequency updates to PouchDB (Document update conflict)

Tags: javascript, promise, pouchdb

I have a method for getting/updating state that's stored within PouchDB. This method gets called by a constructor of an element to assign a user-friendly unique tag to the element. The simplified version of the code looks like this:

```
var tagList = [ /* set of dictionary words to cycle through */ ];
function generateTag(id) {
    return db.get('tags').then(function (tagData) {
        var tag = '', remainder = tagData.tagCount, quotient;

        while (remainder >= tagList.length) {
            quotient = Math.floor(remainder / tagList.length);
            tag += tagList[quotient - 1];
            remainder -= tagList.length * quotient;
        }
        tag += tagList[remainder];
        tag = tag.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + tag.slice(1);

        tagData.tagCount++;
        tagData.tags[tag] = id;

        db.put(tagData);
        return tag;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}

class Element {
    constructor() {
        var self = this;
        generateTag('element' + Date.now()).then(function (tag) {
            self.tag = tag;
        });
    }
}
```

This logic works as expected when there is a delay between creating elements. But when elements are created in a rapid burst (i.e. a for loop), the `db.get` call for 2nd, 3rd, and consecutive elements gets called before the `db.put` operation for first element finishes, resulting in "Document update conflict" messages for consecutive elements. At first I thought PouchDB's conflict resolution would automatically handle this for me, but I was wrong.

Maybe I'm not understanding proper way of handling such cases, or is there a better way of writing this? What I need is for consecutive `db.get` calls to effectively block until the ongoing `db.put` from previous operation finishes. I was thinking perhaps even keeping a static link to the promise corresponding to last PouchDB operation on 'tags' object, such that instead of `db.get('tags')` I'd run `tagsPromise.then(function () { return db.get('tags'); })`, but I'm still a rookie with promises and don't know if that would be a desirable way of addressing this issue or if this issue is even a real issue or something I imposed on myself by not sticking with a better approach?

**UPDATE:**
It looks like modifying the logic to always return a promise and always start with a "singleton" promise instead of `db.get('tags')` in `generateTag` function as I mentioned does fix the issue, still want to understand if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To others interested, this is how I rewrote the above logic using the `tagPromise` approach I mentioned in the update (if there is a better answer from PouchDB experts, I'll accept that instead):

```
var tagList = [ /* set of dictionary words to cycle through */ ];
var tagPromise = db.get('tags');
function generateTag(id, callback) {
    tagPromise = tagPromise.then(function() {
        return db.get('tags');
    }).then(function (tagData) {
        var tag = '', remainder = tagData.tagCount, quotient;

        while (remainder >= tagList.length) {
            quotient = Math.floor(remainder / tagList.length);
            tag += tagList[quotient - 1];
            remainder -= tagList.length * quotient;
        }
        tag += tagList[remainder];
        tag = tag.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + tag.slice(1);

        tagData.tagCount++;
        tagData.tags[tag] = id;
        callback(tag);

        return db.put(tagData);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}

class Element {
    constructor() {
        var self = this;
        generateTag('element' + Date.now(), function (tag) {
            self.tag = tag;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to follow what you are trying to achieve. Could you post the tags document and examples of the elements and tags?

At first glance, getting and updating a single 'tags' document looks quite smelly, I think it would make much more sense to use a view. But for an informed response, I'd need more details please! Thanks!